# for each not updating variables

Tags: actionscript-3, foreach

When using the AS3 for each construct I find that I can't update the members of the array that im iterating.

```
for each( obj:Object in array ){
    obj = new Object();
}
```

when I loop over the array again they will still have the same values as before the loop.

Am I stuck with using tradition for-loops in this situation or is there a way to make the updates stick.

Comment: its because you are updating the reference to the object in `obj`. use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Think of for each loops as being kind of like read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel indicated, you are instantiating a new object to the `obj` reference instead of the array element.  Instead, access the array by ordinal:

```
var array:Array = [{}, {}, {}];

for (var i:uint = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i] = {};
}
```

Comment: Why are you using uint instead of int?  Not questioning, just figure there's a particular reason.

Comment: Ordinal cannot be negative; therefore, `i` when unsigned can iterate from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Comment: Oh, I thought uint was something different.  Thanks.

Comment: Some compilers will implement `i` as `-1`, then `++i` as an optimization.  But here, it is just to gain an additional 2,147,483,647 iterations.